# Query ajax converter post

Tags: php, jquery

$.ajax instead $.post 
$.ajax converter $.post 
Instead I want the use Ajax post

my js code

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "signup.php",
data: "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&password="+password+"&username="+username,     
success : function(login){
if(login=='ok') {               
window.location="index.php";
}else{                       
$("#message").html(login);
}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want, what do you mean by $post? And what do you mean about a converter? Are you trying to change a `POST` to an `ajax` request? Is there an error message?

Comment: No error
I want to use post instead of ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the $.post use this:

```
$.post('signup.php', {name:name,email:email,password:password,username:username}, function(login){
    if(login=='ok') {               
        window.location="index.php";
    }else{                       
        $("#message").html(login);
    }
});
```

Comment: @ErdemJ vote positive please :) thank you!

Comment: Ok
var password=$('#password').val(); 
What is the use of the right

Comment: Thank you again having problems

Comment: @ErdemJ there should be a tick button on the left of the post, which allows you to accept an answer. If it doesn't work fully of course you can leave a comment, giving the person chance to change the answer a bit. The up arrow is also a way of saying thanks for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "signup.php",
  data: {name:name,email:email,password:password,username:username},     
  success : function(login){
    if(login=='ok') {               
     window.location="index.php";
    }else{                       
      $("#message").html(login);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: $.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});

Comment: @ErdemJ I don't understand your comment

Comment: How can I do it this way

Comment: @ErdemJ you want the $.post or the $.ajax method?

Comment: Is not it safe

$ .post

Comment: @ErdemJ you need to improve your english. I can't understand what you want. In my answer, I provided you the way to make an ajax call sending parameters via POST method